# Node.js & Redis: Another redis request in a previous redis request's call back

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm hoping there are some experienced Redis developer that can explain me the logic behind this.

I have a set as a key and I am able to pull all objects stored in set with this code;

```
redisClient.smembers("student_list", function(err,result){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            list = result;
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

This works perfectly fine but this set contains the id of students and in another redis db, I mapped the id's with student's information(JSON string). However when I put a function inside it like after the **console.log(result)** it **does not run** the second Redis query which gets the information of all students. I've written like;

```
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        console.log(i);
        redisClient.get(list[i],function(err,student){
            if(err)
                console.log("An error occured: "+err);
            else
                console.log(JSON.parse(student));
        });
    }
```

I, of course, tried putting this function outside the **smembers** call back. However when I do that, due to the async nature of Node, it simply tries to over an empty list. After loop **not working** I see that console.log(results) method working, but since loop is passed I cannot fetch any data. 1) Is my approach wrong? 2) Is it impossible to call a Redis query inside of another Redis query's callback function. (If they are **dependent** what could be done in order to overcome?)

**PS:** When I try run a Redis query in another's callback I receive this error;

```
Error in get: Redis connection gone from close event.
```

**PS2:**  Full code, just in case;

```
redisClient.smembers("student_list", function(err,result){
        if(err)
            console.log("Err: " + err);
        else {
            list = result;
            console.log(result);

            for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
                console.log(i);
                redisClient.get(list[i],function(err,student){
                    if(err)
                        console.log("An error occured: "+err);
                    else
                        console.log(JSON.parse(student));
                });
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: What is inside the result of "student_list"? There is no limitation to how many nested callbacks you can have and doing what you are wanting to do is what people do. strange. post full code?

Comment: Result inside the student list: `[ '5072a3e59d745ba2a2000002', '5072a3dc9d745ba2a2000001']`

Comment: search for the error on google. seems redis2.6 should potentially fix this issue (upgrade!). Also, listen to the error event on the redisClient.

Comment: @japrescott I did search for it, before even writing here. I downloaded the 2.6 (well it installed 2.5.14, the release candidate for 2.6) but it still gives me the same error. If you have any code that includes the nested functions in Redis, would you please share?

Comment: I don't have an example I can share. But checkout https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/master/examples/subqueries.js

Comment: your welcome :) hope you figure out what the problem is. And answering your question on stackoverflow in the end yourself would be great for everybody else to learn from.